# hosted Blazor WebAssembly use an existing, external Identity Server

Tags: identityserver4, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-hosted

Hi I have a hosted WebAssembly project. I have managed to implement IS4 on the client side using the the standalone method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio.

I can not however find a guide to secure the server api side. Any help would be greatly appreciated